Match a nested JSON field value in Big query GCP
I have a nested JSON payload which contains multiple field value pairs and I would like to put a condition to match and unmatch some values.
For example below is my sample payload -
 responseContent: ""[{\"provider\":\"test\",\"services\":[\"broadband\"],\"status\":\"MatchFailed\",\"data\":{\"code\":\"1234567\",\"description\":\"notfound\"}}]""

I want to do something like where I can negate the payloads with above status value which is MatchFailed.
I am writing a query like this but it is returning no results -
 SELECT
  (REGEXP_EXTRACT(JSON_VALUE(json_payload.proxy_details.responseContent), r'status\\":\\"(.*?)\\')) as status
    FROM
      `prj.global._Default._Default` AS logs
    WHERE
      log_name = "projects/prj/logs/logs"
      AND JSON_VALUE(json_payload.proxy_details.responseContent, '$.status') = "MatchPending"


what is your expected output ? is your problem about the where caluse or the regex ? if regex then we don't see the sample data of .proxy_details.responseContent that you are using in the regex.  Can you provide complete details on what is missing and what is expected and how does the data look like

Your JSON root level is an array rather than object hence you have to access it using the index number see the two examples below:
with main as (

SELECT 
    1 AS id,
    '''
    [
        {
            "provider": "test",
            "services": ["broadband"],
            "status": "MatchFailed",
            "data": {
                "code": "1234567",
                "description": "notfound"
            }
        }
    ]
    ''' AS json_data

)

select *,
safe_case(json_value(json_data, "$[0].status") as string) as status
 from  main
where safe_case(json_value(json_data, "$[0].status") as string) != 'MatchFailed'


vs
with main as (

SELECT 
    1 AS id,
    '''

    {
        "provider": "test",
        "services": ["broadband"],
        "status": "MatchFailed",
        "data": {
            "code": "1234567",
            "description": "notfound"
        }
    }

    ''' AS json_data

)

select *,
safe_case(json_value(json_data, "$.status") as string) as status from main
where safe_case(json_value(json_data, "$.status") as string) != 'MatchFailed'


